# using JSONP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jsonp, wikipedia-api

I have a page where i am using the wikipedia api. But since i cannot use `JSON` for cross domain restrictions i use `JSONP`. Now i can use the api if i query like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function res(data){
  alert(data);
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=api&callback=res&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json">
</script>
```

but i want to use this using `AJAX`. How can i do this? Some people suggested that i use jQuery but can somebody explain how do i do it in plain javascript?

> Is in't there some way that i can use JSONP with asynchronous XHR calls?

Creating and then removing the script element is something i want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

JSONP calls are not asynchronous in nature since they use `script` tags. YOu can defer their execution by appending those tags later programmatically like this:

```
sendJsonpRequest = function (url, callback) {
    if (!(url && callback)) { return; }

    // create script element
    var script = document.createElement("script"),
        jsonpCallback = "jsonp_" + new Date(),
        done = false;

    url = url.replace(/\&$/, "") + "&callback=" + jsonpCallback;

    window[jsonpCallback] = function (args) {
        callback(args);

        // Garbage collect
        window[jsonpCallback] = undefined;
        try { delete window[jsonpCallback]; } catch (e) { }
        if (head) { head.removeChild(script); }
    };

    script.src = url;
    head.appendChild(script);
};
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but what do u mean by  getSalt()??

Comment: @Mrchief did u get this code from some url? if yes please give that url?

Comment: Oh no, its from my own snippets. `getSalt()` is to just get a random string, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Plain Javascript JSONP library: http://blog.eood.cn/jsonp-library-in-plain-javascript-with-timeout